# How to generate alphabetical list in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to create alphatical list with a link in xslt such as;

```
<a href="sample.htm?letter=A">A</a>
<a href="sample.htm?letter=B">B</a>
<a href="sample.htm?letter=C">C</a>
...up to..
<a href="sample.htm?letter=Z">Z</a>
```

It can be a xml then transform

```
<node>
    <letter>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</text>
</node>
```

or just a varible?

```
<xsl:variable name="letter">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:variable name="url">sample.htm</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="letter">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="iterate">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$letter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="iterate">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="length" select="1" />

        <xsl:if test="string-length($string)">

            <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($string, 1, 1)" />

            <xsl:call-template name="createEntry">
                <xsl:with-param name="token" select="$char"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="iterate">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $char)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="createEntry">
        <xsl:param name="token"/>
        <a href="{$url}?letter={$token}"><xsl:value-of select="$token"/></a><br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**

Store the alphabet into a variable like you suggested.

Pass the whole string into a function `iterate` as param `string`. [optional parameter: `length`]

Pass the single char to function `createEntry`.

Function `createEntry` does the output.

*If you like, give it a up*

Comment: Thanks sir. Its better I think :) I'll give it an up

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing. Finally I got it! For those who needs it for future reference. Here's my code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:variable name="url">sample.htm</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="letter">
    <xsl:call-template name="element"><xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="element">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring($text, 1, 1)" />

    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <a href="{$url}?letter={$token}"><xsl:value-of select="$token"/></a><br/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($text) > 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="element">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 2, string-length($text) - 1)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if you have a better or simpler solution kindly comment.